# KotlinNullPointerException In toLedgerTransaction()

Tags: corda

What reasons can be, that i get KotlinNullPointerException when i try to use `txBuilder.toLedgerTransaction(getServiceHub())`? I used `verify()` and then i realised that problem is in toLedgerTransaction(). This problem appeared when i add  new fields to State. They had `co.paralleluniverse.common.util.Pair` type and i think that there are some problems with serialization. Error message:

```
"stackTrace": [
    {
        "methodName": "reportGet",
        "fileName": null,
        "lineNumber": -1,
        "className": "java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture",
        "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
        "methodName": "get",
        "fileName": null,
        "lineNumber": -1,
        "className": "java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture",
        "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
        "methodName": "get",
        "fileName": "CordaFutureImpl.kt",
        "lineNumber": -1,
        "className": "net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImpl",
        "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
        "methodName": "createProject",
        "fileName": "ClientHttpApi.java",
        "lineNumber": 136,
        "className": "com.template.api.ClientHttpApi",
        "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
        "methodName": "invoke0",
        "fileName": null,
        "lineNumber": -2,
        "className": "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl",
        "nativeMethod": true
    },
    {
        "methodName": "invoke",
        "fileName": null,
        "lineNumber": -1,
        "className": "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl",
        "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
        "methodName": "invoke",
        "fileName": null,
        "lineNumber": -1,
        "className": "sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl",
        "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
        "methodName": "invoke",
        "fileName": null,
        "lineNumber": -1,
        "className": "java.lang.reflect.Method",
        "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
        "methodName": "invoke",
        "fileName": "ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java",
        "lineNumber": 81,
        "className": "org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1",
        "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
        "methodName": "run",
        "fileName": "AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java",
        "lineNumber": 144,
        "className": "org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1",
        "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
        "methodName": "invoke",
        "fileName": "AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java",
        "lineNumber": 161,
        "className": "org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher",
        "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
        "methodName": "doDispatch",
        "fileName": "JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java",
        "lineNumber": 160,
        "className": "org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker",
        "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
        "methodName": "dispatch",
        "fileName": "AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java",
        "lineNumber": 99,
        "className": "org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher",
        "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
        "methodName": "invoke",
        "fileName": "ResourceMethodInvoker.java",
        "lineNumber": 389,
        "className": "org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker",
        "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
        "methodName": "apply",
        "fileName": "ResourceMethodInvoker.java",
        "lineNumber": 347,
        "className": "org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker",
        "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
        "methodName": "apply",
        "fileName": "ResourceMethodInvoker.java",
        "lineNumber": 102,
        "className": "org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker",
        "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
        "methodName": "run",
        "fileName": "ServerRuntime.java",
        "lineNumber": 326,
        "className": "org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2",
        "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
        "methodName": "call",
        "fileName": "Errors.java",
        "lineNumber": 271,
        "className": "org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1",
        "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
        "methodName": "call",
        "fileName": "Errors.java",
        "lineNumber": 267,
        "className": "org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1",
        "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
        "methodName": "process",
        "fileName": "Errors.java",
        "lineNumber": 315,
        "className": "org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors",
        "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
        "methodName": "process",
        "fileName": "Errors.java",
        "lineNumber": 297,
        "className": "org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors",
        "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
        "methodName": "process",
        "fileName": "Errors.java",
        "lineNumber": 267,
        "className": "org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors",
        "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
        "methodName": "runInScope",
        "fileName": "RequestScope.java",
        "lineNumber": 317,
        "className": "org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope",
        "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
        "methodName": "process",
        "fileName": "ServerRuntime.java",
        "lineNumber": 305,
        "className": "org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime",
        "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
        "methodName": "handle",
        "fileName": "ApplicationHandler.java",
        "lineNumber": 1154,
        "className": "org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler",
        "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
        "methodName": "serviceImpl",
        "fileName": "WebComponent.java",
        "lineNumber": 473,
        "className": "org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent",
        "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
        "methodName": "service",
        "fileName": "WebComponent.java",
        "lineNumber": 427,
        "className": "org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent",
        "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
        "methodName": "service",
        "fileName": "ServletContainer.java",
        "lineNumber": 388,
        "className": "org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer",
        "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
        "methodName": "service",
        "fileName": "ServletContainer.java",
        "lineNumber": 341,
        "className": "org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer",
        "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
        "methodName": "service",
        "fileName": "ServletContainer.java",
        "lineNumber": 228,
        "className": "org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer",
        "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
        "methodName": "handle",
        "fileName": "ServletHolder.java",
        "lineNumber": 841,
        "className": "org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder",
        "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
        "methodName": "doHandle",
        "fileName": "ServletHandler.java",
        "lineNumber": 535,
        "className": "org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler",
        "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
        "methodName": "nextHandle",
        "fileName": "ScopedHandler.java",
        "lineNumber": 188,
        "className": "org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler",
        "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
        "methodName": "doHandle",
        "fileName": "ContextHandler.java",
        "lineNumber": 1253,
        "className": "org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler",
        "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
        "methodName": "nextScope",
        "fileName": "ScopedHandler.java",
        "lineNumber": 168,
        "className": "org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler",
        "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
        "methodName": "doScope",
        "fileName": "ServletHandler.java",
        "lineNumber": 473,
        "className": "org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler",
        "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
        "methodName": "nextScope",
        "fileName": "ScopedHandler.java",
        "lineNumber": 166,
        "className": "org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler",
        "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
        "methodName": "doScope",
        "fileName": "ContextHandler.java",
        "lineNumber": 1155,
        "className": "org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler",
        "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
        "methodName": "handle",
        "fileName": "ScopedHandler.java",
        "lineNumber": 141,
        "className": "org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler",
        "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
        "methodName": "handle",
        "fileName": "HandlerCollection.java",
        "lineNumber": 126,
        "className": "org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection",
        "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
        "methodName": "handle",
        "fileName": "HandlerWrapper.java",
        "lineNumber": 132,
        "className": "org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper",
        "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
        "methodName": "handle",
        "fileName": "Server.java",
        "lineNumber": 561,
        "className": "org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server",
        "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
        "methodName": "handle",
        "fileName": "HttpChannel.java",
        "lineNumber": 334,
        "className": "org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel",
        "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
        "methodName": "onFillable",
        "fileName": "HttpConnection.java",
        "lineNumber": 251,
        "className": "org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection",
        "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
        "methodName": "succeeded",
        "fileName": "AbstractConnection.java",
        "lineNumber": 279,
        "className": "org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback",
        "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
        "methodName": "fillable",
        "fileName": "FillInterest.java",
        "lineNumber": 104,
        "className": "org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest",
        "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
        "methodName": "run",
        "fileName": "ChannelEndPoint.java",
        "lineNumber": 124,
        "className": "org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2",
        "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
        "methodName": "runJob",
        "fileName": "QueuedThreadPool.java",
        "lineNumber": 679,
        "className": "org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool",
        "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
        "methodName": "run",
        "fileName": "QueuedThreadPool.java",
        "lineNumber": 597,
        "className": "org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2",
        "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
        "methodName": "run",
        "fileName": null,
        "lineNumber": -1,
        "className": "java.lang.Thread",
        "nativeMethod": false
    }
],
"localizedMessage": "kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException: net.corda.core.contracts.TransactionState -> data(net.corda.core.contracts.ContractState) -> null",
"message": "kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException: net.corda.core.contracts.TransactionState -> data(net.corda.core.contracts.ContractState) -> null",
"suppressed": []
```

Stack trace ends with a call of flow through CordaRPCOps, so it's not useful.

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace please? :)

Comment: @Joel I updated.

Comment: Where are you calling `toLedgerTransaction`? Is it in a flow? If so, how are you starting the flow?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are implementing an old syntax of verifying the transaction. With the later versions of Corda, the `TransactionBuilder` object is already able to call the `verify()` method.

For example:

```
// Build the transaction, add the output state and the command to the transaction.
        TransactionBuilder transactionBuilder = new TransactionBuilder(notary)
                .addOutputState(output)
                .addCommand(new AssetContract.Commands.CreateAsset(),
                            Arrays.asList(getOurIdentity().getOwningKey())); // Required Signers

// Verify the transaction
transactionBuilder.verify(getServiceHub());
```

Full codes at: 
https://github.com/corda/samples-java/blob/master/Advanced/auction-cordapp/workflows/src/main/java/net/corda/samples/flows/CreateAssetFlow.java#L59